# Document method-summary with ambigious reference

Tags: c#, code-documentation

I have a massively overloaded method `MethodA` which is referenced by the summary-tag within my documentation of `MethodB`:

```
/// <summary>A link to <see cref="MethodA" /></summary>
void MethodB { ... }
```

The comment should not only rely to a special overload of `MethodA` but to all of them. However compiler prints ammessage that the cref-attribute is ambigious (which is however intended). Are there any best practices to solve this issue? I already thought of completely remove the `see`-tag from the `summary`. Maybe you have some other approaches?

Comment: What about saying `A link to <see cref="MethodA(int)" /> or one of the overloads`?

Comment: That would rely `MethodB` only to that specific overload, not to all of them

Comment: I know, but I think with `see cref` you need to reference a specific method, not a method group.

Comment: Maybe I´d just take the most common overload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 2 options. Either refer to a specific method in the comment:

```
/// <summary>A link to <see cref="MethodA(int)" /> or one of it's overloaded variants</summary>
```

Alternatively, you can add the [`M:` prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsbx0t7x.aspx) which will remove the error though may not be quite what you require:

```
/// <summary>A link to <see cref="M:MethodA" /></summary>
```

Comment: I´m not sure how this works, but it worked. How does the `M:` resolve the ambiguity or does it anyway? I only found out that it referes to a method from your link.

Comment: I believe when you use a prefix the values are not checked for existence any more, though I'm not 100% sure.